# Tooling Api Access for non admin profile

Tags: apex

Trying to access Layout object using tooling API from a non-admin profile but it is not accessible.

Could anyone please help to let me know which permission I am missing?

I have tried providing the "View All Data" permission but it didn't work for me.

However, I saw somewhere we need to provide "Manage users" permission and it worked but the problem is "Manage users" permission comes with other 13 permissions and I didn't want that. Please suggest

Comment: Please take a moment to visit the [help], scroll through the [tour], and read [ask]. As it stands, this question lacks sufficient detail to answer. Any time you get an error message, please include it ***verbatim***. Please **[edit]** your post to include this information, or it will likely be closed.

Answer (score 1):

The [Tooling API documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/intro_rest_overview.htm) clearly states, "View All Data":

> REST Resources give you access to Tooling API objects. To query
>   Tooling API objects using REST resources, you need the “View All Data”
>   user permission.

Comment: Already given the "View All Data" user permission

Comment: Please update your post to include relevant information, as is it is mostly be flagged and put on hold and other peeps wont waste their time suggesting things you have already done.